# New `using` syntax interaction with long lived references

Tags: c#, dispose, using

Here's some example code;

```
public sealed class HoldingClass : IDisposable
{
  private BinaryReader _binaryReaderField;

  public string GetStringFromReader(int count)
  {
    var data = _binaryReaderField.ReadBytes(count);
    // ... Process data ... //
    return newString;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    _binaryReaderField?.Close();
    _binaryReaderField?.Dispose();
  }
}

// ... somewhere else ... //

public sealed class EntryPoint : IDisposable
{
  public static Start(string filePath)
  {
    using var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filePath));
    return new EntryPoint { _holdingClass = new HoldingClass(br) };
  }

  private HoldingClass _holdingClass;

  public string GetString(int count)
  {
    return _holdingClass.GetStringFromReader(count);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    _holdingClass?.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Please note this is a contrived example to express the behaviour I'm interested in and does not represent any sort of production code.

Ok, so in the above code let's say the application starts up with `using var ep = EntryPoint.Start("someFile.txt");` and later on in the method after some other processing occurs, the developer then calls `ep.GetString(155);`.

**What is the behaviour of the `BinaryReader` `using` statement?**

"Common-sense" says to me that as soon as you leave the scope of the `EntryPoint.Start` method, the object is disposed. Any attempt to use it later through the `HoldingClass` instance will result in an `ObjectDisposed` exception.
However, I don't know quite how the new `using` intelligent behaviour works. Is it done by reference counting? In which case the `BinaryReader` object would stay alive throughout the life of the `HoldingClass` instance.

In C++ I would solve this by instantiating a unique pointer and transferring ownership to the new object, but C# doesn't work like that, as far as I know.

Comment: The `using` ends at the end of the scope it is in. So the end of `Start`.

Comment: `the object is disposed and queued up for GC` The former is true. Whether it is "queued up for GC" (which I would nitpick, terminology wise, on a number of points) is irrelevant to the `using`. The `using` does one thing, and one thing only, it creates a `finally` behind the scenes and calls `Dispose` in it. Nothing less, less more.

Comment: `However, I don't know quite how the new using intelligent behaviour works.` It works exactly the same way. It is equivalent to `using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filePath))) {
    return new EntryPoint { _holdingClass = new HoldingClass(br) }; }` The benefit of the new format, vs the old, is that there are a few less characters, and less indentation of the code. It is all syntactic sugar.

Comment: An example for you - https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQBgAIUMA6ASQHkBuXdfOtAZkIG9dDPi002OuBJAJwAKAEQAhAPbAMYgJS0cAge2UqNw8dOBoFSjZqIA3CAkLBzAXkIA7OAHdCEgJa2zATwBKcCABNEEQAxFwAbOFJKAAc4Wx9/cQVFfkMuLUkZJn0UlQBfHMEMUQzgABZs9U58nFygA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new `using` syntax is really just syntactic sugar to reduce "noise" from needing to use braces to show the scope the object should be disposed after. There's no "new" heuristics about it. The equivalent old-style for the code you've posted would be:

```
public static EntryPoint Start(string filePath)
{
    using (using var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)))
    {
        return new EntryPoint { _holdingClass = new HoldingClass(br) };
    }
}
```

In either style, this is a code bug and the holding class would always contain a disposed reference as it is disposed of before the caller ever has access to the `EntryPoint` instance returned by the `Start()` method.

Using old or new syntax, what you're trying to do here isn't an appropriate usage of `using`, and you should omit it with something like:

```
public static EntryPoint Start(string filePath)
{
    var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filePath));
    try
    {
        return new EntryPoint { _holdingClass = new HoldingClass(br) };
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        br.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Here the `BinaryReader` is disposed of if an exception happens while creating the result, but otherwise you need to pass control of it to your `HoldingClass` implementation and have both it and `EntryPoint` implement `IDisposable` and appropriate dispose of it when they are disposed of.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much the clarification I was asking for.

I'd read that the new `using` syntax was "intelligent scope detection" so wondered if it had any new clever behaviour.

Is there anything available that is similar to a C++ Unique Pointer? Essentially, I want to ensure that a developer's disposable object ownership is transferred to my code (what would be the equivalent of the `HoldingClass` in this example, I have no control over the equivalent of `EntryPoint`). Or is this just a "not my problem" deal and I let them get the OD exception when attempting to use the class?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++ to give a comparison to Unique Pointer. Maybe you could come up with something similar to the `StreamWriter` class where the caller can explicitly pass control of a disposable object (or not) to the other code using the `leaveOpen` parameter? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_System_Boolean_

Comment: That would be the wrong way around for me, but thanks for your help. I think the difinitive answer here is "you can't" :)